# Changing Spreadsheetgear axis title orientation on a column chart

Tags: spreadsheetgear

I am using Spreadsheetgear to create charts in Excel. I create a column chart with an axis title on the y-axis.

```
chart.Axes[SpreadsheetGear.Charts.AxisType.Value].HasTitle = true;
chart.Axes[SpreadsheetGear.Charts.AxisType.Value].AxisTitle.Text = "Market Value";
```

However, the axis tile is in a horizontal orientation. I want it in a vertical orientation, but have not been able to find a way to do that in my code. (In Excel, I can rotate the axis title changing its orientation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axis title rendering support, as well as rotated text support, was added in SpreadsheetGear 2009.

Here is an example of changing the axis title orientation from the API:

```
SpreadsheetGear.Charts.IAxis axis = chart.Axes[SpreadsheetGear.Charts.AxisType.Value];
axis.HasTitle = true;
axis.AxisTitle.Text = "Market Value";
axis.AxisTitle.Orientation = -90;
```

Comment: I am still using SpreadsheetGear 2008. I guess I need to upgrade.